# Codcademy help, variable not working

Tags: javascript

I am learning js using codecademy, it tells me I have passed the lesson, however it does not look successful to me and I would like to understand where I've gone wrong to help me learn as it offers no help because it says I've successfully completed the lesson. So any help would be appreciated :)

I have made a very basic rock, paper, scissors game.

I cannot get it to declare which has won, rock, paper or scissors. The **compare** variable does not 'output' anything.

It should say 'Rock wins' or 'scissors wins' or 'The result is a tie!' etc but all it does is say 'User picks Rock Computer picks scissors'

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
} console.log("User picks" + " " + userChoice + " " + "Computer picks" + " " + computerChoice);

var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if(choice1 === choice2) {
        console.log("The result is a tie!");
    }
    else if(choice1 === "rock") {
        if(choice2 === "scissors") {
            console.log("rock wins")
        }
        else {
            console.log("paper wins")
        }
    }
    else if(choice1 === "paper")  {
        if(choice2 === "rock") {
            console.log("paper wins")
        }
        else {
            console.log("scissors wins")
        }
    }
    else if(choice1 === "scissors") {
        if(choice2 === "paper") {
            console.log("scissors wins")
        }
        else {
            console.log("rock wins")
        }
    }
};
compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
```

Comment: you dont need to use === for string comparisons, == will suffice.

Comment: Your code works fine https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/17267/.

Comment: are you typing in rock with a capital `R` ?  that doesnt have a case in your if and would trigger the behavior youre describing.

Comment: I think the code only outputs anything when used in codecademy.com's editor. Thanks for trying to help guys I appreciate it. Unfortunately I think I can't explain well enough what isn't occurring as we see different things in the jsfiddle to what I see on codecadmey.

Comment: @Rooster actually I was typing it with an upper-case without realising, thank you for the help! Sorry this was such a simple question but I wanted to be sure I understood before moving on

Comment: Hope your course goes well! I also learned js on codecademy. KhanAcademy and Codeschool are good too.

Comment: :) I'll check those out after I complete this @KaiChristensen thanks for the suggestions

Comment: Codecademy have a forum

Comment: @DanielG Yeh, that's true but it's quite inactive and I know Stackoverflow has a great community of people who could answer quite quickly, as I'm eager to continue learning but didn't want to carry on to the next lessons when I didn't fully understand something I had done

Comment: @GoldenGonaz No problem for me, I pasted here my old code because I also used codecademy, enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
computerChoice = "scissors";
} console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
if (choice1 === choice2) {
    return "The result is a tie!";
} else if (choice1 === "rock") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
        return "rock wins";
    } else {
        return "paper wins";
    }
} else if (choice1 === "paper") {
    if (choice2 === "rock") {
        return "paper wins";
    } else {
        return "scissors wins";
    }
} else if (choice1 === "scissors") {
    if (choice2 === "rock") {
        return "rock wins";
    } else {
        return "scissors wins";
    }
}
};
compare(userChoice,computerChoice);
```

PS:The Math.random() function returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range [0, 1) that is, from 0 (inclusive) up to but not including 1 (exclusive), which you can then scale to your desired range. The implementation selects the initial seed to the random number generation algorithm; it cannot be chosen or reset by the user.

Comment: This is just an exercise from codecademy.com if you wish to know more about this code I encourage you to take the free course

Comment: I have. I was asking you to elaborate on what you changed to help the OP, not me, and create a better answer.

Comment: @KaiChristensen I think it's pretty clear what does this code and what it lacks

Answer (score 1):

I was answering the prompt with the wrong case 'Rock' instead of 'rock'. The code is working if using the correct case.

Comment: If you want to add additional functionality that will allow the user to type in "Rock" and have it still work, convert `choice1` to all lowercase after it has been assigned values by using something like: `choice1 = choice1.toLowerCase();` on the first line of the function declaration.

Comment: Brilliant, I'll make a note of that that will be helpful thanks